# is shell a command line interface if so why we need terminals

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal

I have seen in linux the option "open in terminal" when you do right click. If shell itself is command line interface then it can by its own take input from keyboard and display it in console. Then why we need terminal or terminal emulator.

I know there is a similar question but the answer is not clear from the explanation provided here:
[What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

Comment: I think the answer you linked is much more clear than your question.

Comment: one irrelevant but obvious reason - colors.

Comment: Imagine shell (i.e bash) as a complete orchestra composed by violins, pianos, guitars, etc. You can ask orchestra to play any song by giving notes (using a terminal) to maestro. Maestro understands only partitures (bash script). Right click & open in terminal equals to show me the partiture.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear, but let me try a shot in the dark, since you say the possible duplicate didn't help you...

When you right-click in linux the option "open in terminal", you are starting off in a GUI environment, so what you type isn't going to **any** *command line*. If you are using a GUI such as gnome3, that can seem confusing because such GUIs now allow you to type some command names to launch programs, but those GUIs aren't shells - think of that kind of typing as working with a menu (eg. `dmenu`, `rofi`).

Thus, in order to get to a shell command-line from within the GUI, you need to launch some kind of program that will have that command line ... a terminal emulator.